# Remove Facebook bookmark red notification after click

Tags: facebook, notifications

I'm developing a facebook app and sending requests to users. when a user enter the app there are red notifications of all the requests in the bookmark zone, but on click the red notifications don't disappear. only after the next time he enter the app. is there a way to remove the red notifications after click? just to make sure, i'm not talking about the main red notifications in the top facebook banner. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove requests manually to hide count from application bookmark.

Cite from "Notifying Users on Requests" section of [`Requests Dialog` documentation.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

> You must read and clear requests using the Graph API when the user has clicked through to your app. For more information, see the [Deleting Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#deleting) section.